# Rails 4 - No route matches PATCH on custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need a page for changing Profile of current user, it's weird if the url is `/user/:id`, so I map it to `/settings`

```
get "/settings", to: "users#edit", as: "settings_user"
```

But when I submit the form I got this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [PATCH] "/settings"
```

The weird part is if I press back and re-submit the form, it will submit just fine.

If I go to another page then back to the form, it will get error on first try but works fine on second try onward.

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def edit
    @user = current_user #this is the cache of currently logged in user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
     redirect_to settings_user_path, notice: "Profile has been saved"
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :email, :bio)
    end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**Note**:

Other page that are using the default route like my Product page works fine, so it's not the Rails config problem.

Comment: you're defining a `get` route, and trying to use `patch`, and wondering why it's not working...?

Comment: The form action is `/users/1` which I already set with `resources :users, only: [:update]`. But Rails insist that the form is submitted to `/settings`

Answer (score 1):

**Devise**

I guess you're using `devise` (by how you're using `current_user`) - so you may wish to look at Devise' [`custom routing paths`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes). Although this won't provide a routing structure for your `user` object, it may come in handy some time:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, path: "auth", path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

--

**Routes**

If you want to manage your `user` object, you'll be best using the `resources` route definition:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [], path: "" do
   collection do
       get :settings, action: :edit
       match :settings, action :update, via: [:patch, :put]
   end
end
```

The problem you have is your `form` is thinking it should send your `update` request to `/settings` too:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/settings"
```

The way around this is to either provide a route for `patch` (as demonstrated above), OR define the `url` parameter of the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: your_update_path do |f| %>
```

--

Hope this helps?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I'm not using `Devise` or similar gem, I just follow their naming scheme. I will try the nested routes and report back shortly

Comment: Thanks Darc - Apologies about Devise. I'll leave up though in case someone *is* using Devise & they see the answer in the future?

Comment: Yeah, you can keep the Devise comment. For the nested routes, the URL become this format: `/users/:user_id/settings` which defeats my main purpose of short URL. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Sure - plenty! Let me refactor for you

Comment: Bit long winded, but what I recommended should create `domain.com/settings` - taking you to `users/edit` page ;)

Answer (score 0):

This issue only occur on Chrome 37 Beta. I reverted back to Chrome 36 Release and everything works fine.

I guess I won't use the beta version for daily use ever again.